# How to get .eml files into .pst files to import into Concordance

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, conversion, thunderbird

I have thousands of .eml files and need to get them into .pst files so I can import them into Concordance.

Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer: [Import-EML-To-Outlook](http://bitdaddys.com/Import-EML-To-Outlook.html)

Comment: "BITDADDYS.COM
Interested in this domain?" looks like to content no longer exists.